# Deploying POJO model on AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, h2o

I'm a newbie in H2O and also AWS.
I have completed couples of GLM model in H2O and would want to deploy it on AWS lambda. Those model consume more or less same source of data which will be injecting in JSON from API Gateway.

What is the most optimal way to score these model in parallel and sum the result from each GLM within one Lambda function?
- Putting each POJO class sequentially in the Lambda is OK?
- there would be some data transformation script needed to transform data into a shape that required by POJO model with some table lookup in Redis
- After 5 POJO scoring is done, need to sum the score and return this out to S3

Is this setup is possible? Or there are other way round is more suitable for this use case. The scoring of GLM(s) model and the result will be deploy for web application and serving user in real-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GLM models score really fast.  It's fine to put them in series within a single lambda API call.  Model prediction latency won't be bad.  The database table lookups will probably dominate the latency.

What's important for high volume transaction problems is that multiple transactions can occur in parallel, and using AWS lambda endpoints is a good way to let Amazon handle that problem instead of having to invent your own way.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I am thinking about to go with a solution to hash the table in sqlite format and zip it in lambda package to reduce the latency as those tables is lookup table and it is pretty small.